# How to make file names sequentially infinite when creating additional files in the Windows form of C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, filenames

Every time I click a button on Windows form, 
I would like to create a program that creates files infinitely and sequentially.

For example,
here is an a.txt file. 
When I create this as a file with a new name in windows form of c# 
I would like to create a-2.txt. 
If I keep adding more files, I would like to make a-3.txt, a-4.txt, a-5.txt .... sequentially infinitely.

For example here are that files.
a-2.txt, a-3.txt, a-4.txt, a-5.txt
If I randomly deleted a-3.txt, a-4.txt, I wonder how to make a-3.txt, a-4.txt, a-6.txt, a-7.txt....every time I click a button on Windows form. 
The reason is that a-2.txt, a-5.txt remain.

Comment: So you'd “like to create a program”? What is stopping you from doing that? You don't have a compiler? You don't know anything about programming at all? Have you tried writing something? Care to show it to us?

Comment: It's impossible. You can't have more than 4,294,967,295 files in a folder.

Comment: If you got even close to 4,294,967,295, you would be needing an award in how not to write software.

Comment: Thank you so much to concern my question. I'm sorry to bother you. I only wonder how to make code or program. I would like to know that. Please help me.

Comment: Thank you so much to concern my question. I'm sorry to bother you. I only wonder how to make code or program. I would like to know that. In other words, I have a question. This is how you make a unique filename by adding a number and then after I delete some files and how to create a file deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't included any code, i will give you a no code answer to point you in the right direction

When you create a file, you will need to list all the files in the directory, separate the numbers, and sort through them for the next available number to know which file name to create.

You can do this by enumerating files in a directory to get a list

```
var fileList = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath);
```

Then you are left with the easy problems of pulling apart those file paths to get the names, then breaking apart the names to make a list of numbers, then finding which number you should create next

To get the file name from the path you can use, `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`

To get the number from the file name you could user `RegEx`

To turn the list in to a list of `int` you can use `Linq`

Comment: Sorry to bother you.

Comment: It actually achieves all thr technical problems in a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this, but adding in your local path and as Saruman stated, trimming off returned paths.

The below code should check for a.txt and call another function to create it if it doesn't exists.  If a.txt does exist, it looks for all files with an appropriate name, splits them on "-" and "." to pull out just the number, turns the number into a list and sorts it.

A counter looks for the first gap in the list, if one is found it is used, otherwise an appropriate 1 higher number is chosen.  This was just scrawled out, not tested (VS doesn't want to work at the moment) so you'll possibly have to debug.

```
        if (System.IO.File.Exists("a.txt"))
        {
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^a-\\d+\\.txt$");
            int[] numbers = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("path", "a-*.txt").Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x)).Select(x => int.Parse(x.Split('-', '.')[1])).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
            for (int c = 0; c < numbers.Length; c++)
                if (numbers[c] != c + 2)
                {
                    CreateFile(string.Concat("a-", (c + 2).ToString(), ".txt"));
                    break;
                }
            CreateFile(string.Concat("a-", (numbers.Length + 2).ToString(), ".txt"));
        }
        else
        {
            CreateFile("a.txt");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I will definitely debug your code.  Thank you so much again.

Comment: Could you please tell me what "^a-\\d+\\.txt$ " is ?

Comment: That string is called a regular expression.

A regular expression is an object that describes the format of a string and lets you do things such as say "does the string coming in have such and such format" or "return this part of the string".

Caret matches the beginning of a string, the a and the dash look for an a and a dash respectively.  The backslash d looks for a digit.  The plus makes it so instead of looking for a single digit it will look for one or more digits.  The backslash dot looks for a dot.  The txt looks for txt and the $ looks for the end of a string.

Comment: The end result is we look for a starting that starts with "a-", is followed by 1 or more digits and that is followed by ".txt", after which the string ends.

aa-2.txt would not be matched.
a-2.txt would match.
a-25.txt would match.
a-25.txte would not match.

This would have an error if a-1.txt existed, since the loop after counts on a-1 not existing, but changing .Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x)) to .Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x) && x != "a-1.txt") will get rid of that potential error.

Comment: I am so sorry to answer late. I got it. ^^ Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows API `GetTempFileName` specifying:

- where you want the file
- a prefix string
- whether it should be unique

Spec:

```
UINT WINAPI GetTempFileName(
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpPathName,
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpPrefixString,
  _In_  UINT    uUnique,
  _Out_ LPTSTR  lpTempFileName
);
```

MSDN:

> Creates a name for a temporary file. If a unique file name is generated, an empty file is created and the handle to it is released; otherwise, only a file name is generated.

Specifically:

> uUnique [in]
>   An unsigned integer to be used in creating the temporary file name. For more information, see Remarks.
>
> If uUnique is zero, the function attempts to form a unique file name using the current system time. If the file already exists, the number is increased by one and the functions tests if this file already exists. This continues until a unique filename is found; the function creates a file by that name and closes it. Note that the function does not attempt to verify the uniqueness of the file name when uUnique is nonzero.

### Why use this?

The other answers here, though jolly good, involve you obtaining all the pre-existing files (of which may be many) then computing a filename then testing for uniqueness before creating it by which time a file with the same name could be created by another process. Though `GetTempFileName` has a uniqueness similar loop, it only requires a single call on your part and one line of code and no requirement for filename prefetch.

### More

- [GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and advice.^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program to get the next consecutive id from a list of files then writes a new file with that id:

```
class Program
{

   private static int GetNextId(List<int> ids)
   {
      int i;
      for (i = 0; ids[i] == i; i++); // search for first missing id
      return i;
   }

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var myPath = @"d:\test"; // your path

      var fileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath) // get files in your path
         .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)     // get the file name from the full path
         .ToList(); // convert it to list

      var ids = fileNames.Select(fileName => 
      Convert.ToInt32(fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("-") + 1))) // get the index of dash, then get the rest of the name (id)
         .ToList(); // convert it to a list of int

      ids.Sort(); // sort it to make sure its in order

      var nextFileId = GetNextId(ids); // get the consecutive id 

      // write a new file
      using (var file = File.Create(Path.Combine(myPath, $"myFile-{nextFileId}")))
      {
         // file.write(); write stuff here
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and answer.